# Building a C wrapper for C lib's use in Julia

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, julia

I am trying to use FANN (a C library) in Julia. I need to write a C wrapper to convert things to/from void *, etc.

My problem is that when I try to call my C wrapper from Julia, it fails to find the libfann.so functions: 
"julia: symbol loopup error: --- undefined symbol: fann_create_standard".

I suspect the problem is because libfann is merely linked to from my C wrapper, not completely included.

Here is how I am building it:

myfann.c

```
#include "fann.h"
void * create_standard( unsigned int nl, unsigned int ni, unsigned int nnh, unsigned int no )
{
   fann *ann = fann_create_standard(nl,ni,nnh,no);
   void* retval = fann;
   return retval;
}
... // other methods
```

juliafann.jl

```
ptr = ccall( (:create_standard, "libjlfann"), Ptr{Void}, (Uint32,Uint32,Uint32,Uint32), 3, 2, 3, 1)
ccall( (:destroy, "libjlfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},), ptr)
```

bash script for compiling:

```
gcc -Wall -fPIC -c myfann.c -lfann -lm
gcc -shared -o libjlfann.so -Wl,--whole-archive /usr/local/lib/libfann.so -Wl,--no-whole-archive -Wl,-soname,libjlfann.so.1 -o libjlfann.so.1.0 *.o
sudo rm /opt/lib/libjlfann*
sudo mv libjlfann.so.1.0 /opt/lib
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libjlfann.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libjlfann.so.1
sudo ln -sf /opt/lib/libjlfann.so.1.0 /opt/lib/libjlfann.so
```

Then I just run my julia program with "julia juliafann.jl" and it gets an error.
Julia can find the exported functions just fine, it merely fails when it tries to evaluate the functions from the original fann library that I am trying to wrap.

Thank you. This question should be general enough to apply to arbitrary C wrappers for use in Julia.

Comment: Doesn't Julia's ccall do this for you? Just call it a `void *` instead. I don't think you should need a wrapper in this case. E.g., with `FILE*` from stdio: `fh = ccall(:fopen,Ptr{Void},Ptr{Uint8},Ptr{Uint8}),"test.txt","w")` returns a pointer to Void that you can use in ccalls to fwrite and fclose. You'll need to [dlopen](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/#Base.dlopen) the library first (but I'm not familiar with FANN).

Comment: Well, that does appear to work. I guess C can figure out how to deal with the null pointers. Here is what I am doing:                             ptr = ccall( (:fann_create_standard, "libfann"), Ptr{Void}, (Uint32,Uint32,Uint32,Uint32), 3, 2, 3, 1)                               ccall( (:fann_destroy, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},), ptr)             It appears to work.

Comment: Maybe answer your own question with a tutorial and/or step-by-step instructions so others can do it too?

Comment: Hmm... Not completely resolved. I am having trouble figuring out how to get access to enum constants from Julia. I tried cglobal() but that doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to the overarching problem: using FANN from Julia. This is not a solution to the subproblem: embedding a shared library within another shared library.

Use of a wrapper C library is not strictly necessary. Calls can be done directly from Julia.

Assuming fann is installed on your computer, the following produces identical output, from Julia, when compared to the C version [here](http://leenissen.dk/fann/wp/help/getting-started/).

test_neural.jl

```
num_input = 2
num_output = 1
num_layers = 3
num_neurons_hidden = 3
desired_error = 0.001
max_epochs = 500000
epochs_between_reports = 1000

type NeuralNet
    ptr::Ptr{Void}

    function NeuralNet( nLayers::Integer, nInputs::Integer, nHidden::Integer, nOutput::Integer)
        ptr = ccall( (:fann_create_standard, "libfann"), Ptr{Void}, (Uint32,Uint32,Uint32,Uint32), nLayers, nInputs, nHidden, nOutput)
        smart_p = new(ptr)
        finalizer(smart_p, obj -> ccall( (:fann_destroy, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},), obj.ptr) )
        smart_p
    end
end

ann = NeuralNet( num_layers, num_input, num_neurons_hidden, num_output )

FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC = 5; // determined by looking at source

ccall( (:fann_set_activation_function_hidden, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},Uint32), ann.ptr, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC)
ccall( (:fann_set_activation_function_output, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},Uint32), ann.ptr, FANN_SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC)

ccall( (:fann_train_on_file, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},Ptr{Uint8},Uint32,Uint32,Float32), ann.ptr, bytestring("xor.data"), max_epochs, epochs_between_reports, desired_error )

ccall( (:fann_save, "libfann"), Void, (Ptr{Void},Ptr{Uint8}), ann.ptr, bytestring("xor_float.net"))

# execution
input = [-1 -1]
calc_out = ccall( (:fann_run, "libfann"), Ptr{Float32}, (Ptr{Void},Ptr{Float32}), ann.ptr, float32(input) )
@printf("xor test (%f,%f) -> %f\n", input[1], input[2], unsafe_load(calc_out, 1))
```